# Is SubscriptionClient.RegisterMessageHandler() Using 'Brokered Connections' in Azure Service Bus?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I'm trying to get very specific with estimating pricing using Azure Service Bus. The MS docs are very hard to decipher, but it appears that 'Brokered Connections' are the key variable when it comes to ASB, because in the Standard Tier you get charged for them. As I understand it, Brokered Connections are used with HTTP 'long polling'.

I'm using using this  Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus NuGet package, and listening for messages using the SubscriptionClient and registering a callback to process messages using the RegisterMessageHandler() method.

What I'm trying to figure out is: is this SubscriptionClient using Brokered Connections? If it is, this has a huge impact on my pricing estimate.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm trying to figure out is: is this SubscriptionClient using Brokered Connections? If it is, this has a huge impact on my pricing estimate.

A brokered connection is a connection established to the broker. A connection can be used with the `ManagementClient` over HTTPS or with any other client over TCP port 5671 for AMQP operations (or WebSockets). Each client can either have its own connection or share it. When a client is created using a connection **string**, a new connection is issued. Alternatively, clients can share/pool a [`ServiceBusConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.servicebusconnection?view=azure-dotnet). This will result in multiple clients sharing the same "channel" to talk to the broker. In your code, you'll have to find the balance between sharing connections and creating new ones.

Comment: Thank you for for your response. I'm still a little unclear though - is it really just "..a connection established to the broker"? The MS docs say:

"...An HTTP call to receive a message from a Service Bus topic or queue that has a receive timeout value greater than zero.."

And also:

"...Receiving events with HTTP using a timeout greater than zero, sometimes called "long polling," generate brokered connection charges..."

How do I determine whether the SubscriptionClient is doing this?

Comment: Any client (queue, subscription, topic, or management) requires a connection and those count towards the allowed quota. AMQP is a **protocol** implemented. The connectivity is always over TCP. Hope that clarifies it.

Comment: Ok, but what about an HTTP request with a zero timeout, for instance? The docs imply that's not a billable connection. Does the SubscriptionClient send in a zero timeout? If so, then it's using a protocol (HTTP), but not billable. So this is what I'm unclear about.

Comment: Any connection is billable. Unfortunately, I cannot point to the documentation as it doesn't exist. At least I am not aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer from a separate MSDN post. The answer is:

"The SDK uses AMQP for its connections."

So the SubscriptionClient will definitely be incurring brokered connection charges, because AMQP is always a brokered connection.

Now I just need to figure out the cost impact.

Thanks for your response, Sean!